# How do I convert a time string (e.g. "8:02 AM") to a sortable field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My MongoDB database includes times as strings right now, and I'd like to be able to filter queries between certain times.

For example, time fields in my database look like "8:02 AM"" and "10:20 PM", and I want to be able to filter my results by only those between "8:00 AM" and "9:00 AM". My thinking is to convert every string into a number that is the minute of the day, so for example, "9:00 AM" becomes 540 and "10:20 PM" becomes 1,340, but there has to be a more efficient way to do this. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

I also tried the JavaScript `Date()` but that assumed I was EST and converted the time to GMT which I don't want at all.

Some janky code that seems to work, but I'm certain there's a better way:

```
const time_function = (time) => {
    const split_string = time.replace(" ",":").split(":")
    if(split_string[0]==="12" && split_string[2]==="AM"){
        split_string[0] = "0"
        split_string.push(0)
    } else if(split_string[0]==="12" && split_string[2]==="PM"){
        split_string.push(0)
    } else if(split_string[2]=="PM"){
        split_string.push(720)
    } else if (split_string[2]==="AM"){
    split_string.push(0)
    }
    const minutes = (parseInt(split_string[0])*60)+parseInt(split_string[1])+split_string[3]
    return minutes
}
```

Comment: Why not "9:00AM" -> "0900" which is already a fairly well-established convention. Nobody ever says "meet me at 540" and it means 9am.

Comment: *"converted the time to GMT"*: that might be a misinterpretation. Did you perhaps print the date without calling `.toString` or `.toLocaleString`?

Comment: @trincot I did misinterpret. When I did `console.log(Date("12:42 AM")` it actually returned the current date, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Another example justifying the it is better to store date/time values as proper `Date` objects instead of strings.

Comment: Perhaps library [moments.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) will make your life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the day doesn't seem to matter you could just assume any fix day, convert the string to milliseconds and compare those.

```
const lower = '8:00 AM'
const upper = '9:30 PM'
const time  = '12:24 PM'
const delta_lower = Date.parse(`1/1/1970 ${lower}`)
const delta_upper = Date.parse(`1/1/1970 ${upper}`)
const delta_time  = Date.parse(`1/1/1970 ${time}`)
console.log(delta_time > delta_lower && delta_time < delta_upper) //prints true
```